# how can I save a List of Objects into Redis using only one key - value?

Tags: java, spring, redis

I am trying to do this.

I have a list of objects (Custom objects), I want to save them all in a single register in Redis, is it possible to save them as ajax somehow? I was reading about Jackson but I couldn't figure it how.

So far I only have this

```
@Autowired
private StringRedisTemplate redisTmpl;
```

And I can save like this

```
redisTmpl.opsForValue().set("foo", "bar");
```

Works pretty good, but instead of Bar , I want to save my list of objects (using this `StringRedisTemplate`.

Any idea how to do it?

Or maybe using another way? But I need to save all the list in just one key.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not a Java dev, but you need to serialize that list into JSON and store the JSON string in the whole key........

Comment: Check out the Spring Data Redis docs, you can use different serializers: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer

Comment: `ajax` is negotiation protocol not serialization method, I believe you mean `JSON` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Found the way to do it....

To save all the list you can use jackson, on this way

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(myList);
```

And later you just save it on same way

```
redisTmpl.opsForValue().set("foo", jsonInString);
```

Comment: how can i convert the jsonInString object back into an object. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can serialize your object as `JSON`, you can store it as string in redis. but for this you may need to create  serializer/deserializer methods for your class.

Comment: I am using Jackson for it, and it saves it great, but I cannot get it back in same format (hashmap)

Answer (score 0):

you should use spring support to convert your values to JSON like below example. It also convert your key to string directly.

```
<bean id="serializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value type="java.lang.Class">your.class.path.to.be.saved.in.redis</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
        p:connection-factory-ref="redisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="valueSerializer" ref="serializer"/>
    <property name="keySerializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>
    </property>
   </bean>
```

Comment: @jpganz18 you can use the internal support from spring rides data to convert your object into json format by using serializers as mentioned in the answer... if you find this helpful please vote up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Redisson](https://redisson.org) as well. It supports many codecs like `Jackson JSON`, `Avro`, `Smile`, `CBOR`, `MsgPack`, `Kryo`, `FST`, `LZ4`, `Snappy`
and `JDK Serialization`. It's very easy in use:

```
List<Object> list = ...
redisson.getBucket("yourKey").set(list);

// or use Redis list object

redisson.getList("yourKey").addAll(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [redisson](https://redisson.org) you can do this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
RList<MyObject> list = redissonCLient.getList("myKey");
list.add(mapper.writeValueAsString(new MyObject("test")));
```

The code above will save a Redis List in JSON format with the MyObjects values.

To retrieve the list you can do:

```
RList<MyObject> list = redissonCLient.getList("myKey");
List<MyObject> myObjects = mapper.readValue(list.toString(), new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>(){});
```